# How to load a tabular data file in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I'm a beginner to python and I have a data set contains alphanumeric characters which i need to load them in a python list ,the data consists of 1000 row and 37 column,it looks like :

راؤول   ر   ل   را  ول  راؤ ؤول 0   0   0   0   اؤ  ؤو  5   low noun    na  na  s   na  m   na  UNK NO  1   0   B-emp   NAN arb nd  0   1   0   0   0   0   B-PER

غونزاليس    غ   س   غو  يس  غون ليس نز  ونز ال  الي ون  لي  8   CAP noun_prop   u   na  s   na  m   i   gwnzAlys    YES 1   1   I-emp   NAN arb nd  0   0   1   0   0   0   I-PER

Comment: Can you show some real code which you wrote for the task?

Comment: Thanks a lot,i already solve it and here is my code which run the whole file into a list:

text_file = open('D:/all.dev.features.txt', 'r')
lines = text_file.readlines()
print lines
print len(lines)
for line in lines:
    print line
text_file.close()